# Error found when loading /etc/profile

Tags: 20.10

Error : Error found when loading /etc/profile
Realpath: ./generate/unix/bin : No such file or directory

I’m getting this error in a few places and I’m not sure how to fix it. It pops up when I try to run any desktop environment that’s not Ubuntu gnome on wayland. It also pops up occasionally when I’m using the command line. Any pointers?

I’m on Ubuntu 20.10

[This is the error when I try to run gnome in Xorg mode or any other desktop environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuo0p.jpg)

Comment: Hi you already said what the error is no real need for the picture.

Comment: You cannot use relative Path (relative to your home-directory) in /etc/profile.

Comment: I couldn’t find the path ./generate/unix/bin in my /etc/profile. Is there anywhere else I should look?

Comment: @GeorgeSaker it could be in any one of the files sourced by /etc/profile - by default that includes all `*.sh` files in the `/etc/profile.d` directory.

Comment: Thanks very much steeldriver and Soren A. That solved my issue